# LLDB - set previously used breakpoints

Tags: lldb

Is there a way to set all previously used breakpoints again in LLDB (command line)?

Example:

I started lldb and set:

(lldb) b osDel

(lldb) b rtioctl

[did my debug]

(lldb) quit

Then, I start lldb again and attach it to the same process.
Now I want to set the same breakpoints used earlier.

I already know that is possible to usr Ctrl+r to search previously used commands. But is there a way to set all breakpoints at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the man page and trying things out, I came up with an work around:

you can create a file with all your breakpoint, say

```
file ./my_program

b Car::openDoor

b Car::closeDoor

b Car::pedalToTheMetal
```

and run

```
lldb -S ./my_breakpoints
```

The line 'file ./my_program is needed to find the binary and execute.

Comment: Note, the current TOT lldb now has commands to write & read breakpoints to a save file (`breakpoint read` and `breakpoint write`).  They should show up in the next official releases.